# Making a web player frontend for my media server

Tags: java, apache-flex, frontend

I have a small media server. It's actually a Netgear GoFlex Home (NAS) running Plugbox Linux. It's currently running a bunch of servers HTTP/FTP/WebDAV/DLNA/Webmin etc and I want to create a frontend for my multimedia that I can access from the internet. (I preimarily use it as a DLNA media server).

At first I considered using a Java Servlets backend with a Flex based frontend but that fact that I can't use Flex Builder from work (licensing) and I'm unwilling to pay a few hundred pounds for it, that's out of the question.

After reading a bit, I'm now considering HTML5 frontend, maybe the backend can remain Java Servlets under Tomcat?

Anyone have any suggestions on what might be best to achieve the desired goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flex as front end without using Flex Builder, as Flex SDK is open source, 
you should try building with Maven, it's easier to build your projects using maven

Comment: Do why on earth does it cost £400GBP almost for them to stick a plugin for an opensource SDK onto an opensource IDE??? I'll checkout Maven now. Thanks.

Comment: @Hamid: Nothing is free. People either donate their time or people buy other people's time. Adobe's business is based on selling software, so that is what they will do.

Comment: I understand that perfectly, in fact better than most. But they're pricing individuals out of buying it which stunts the adoption of the platform. I know it's very capable because I use it daily at work. But I can't legitimately afford to run that software for a personal project that I might open source and share for nothing. Donating my time is as much as I can afford to give away...

Comment: Understandable, but perhaps your ire is better directed at work for not letting you take your tool home, than at Adobe for charging for it in the first place.

Comment: My work doesn't disallow me to take the tool home. But that means taking my work computer home.... I'm just confused about Adobe's pricing when I see no part of the package (aside from the branding) that isn't opensource. But this is all aside from my point in starting this thread. Maybe Flex isn't even the best solution?